# Actionscript, locating origin of Error #1010 : A term is undefined and has no propoerties

Tags: actionscript, undefined

I'm getting an error in my Connect-Four program (Actionscript 3.0)
something is wrong with how the Button is being called in my button_clicked function
However, I cannot quite figure out what it is
I had a hunch, that perhaps the get_value() was not working
But the result of this command outputs to two other function
dropcheckerupdate() and find_first_available()
I traced the value in each, and they seem to be working fine
Any help appreciated :)

```
Output:
>2
>2
>TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at Connect_Four/find_first_available()
    at Connect_Four/dropcheckerupdate()
    at Connect_Four/button_clicked()


>Ran debug and it gave me the lines wrapped in ** below
```

The entire "Connect_Four" Class

```
package 
{
    public class Connect_Four extends Sprite
    {
        private var grid: Array;
        private var buttons: Array;
        private var canvas;
        private var radius: int;
        private var distFromCircleToWall: int;
        private var distBetweenCircles: int;
        private var player1Turn: Boolean;

        public function Connect_Four(stageowner: DisplayObjectContainer, >vertical_rows : Number, horizontal_rows : Number, radius : int)
        {
            distFromCircleToWall = (radius * 2) + 10;
            distBetweenCircles = (radius * 2) + 15;

            player1Turn = true; //starts on player ones turn
            canvas = stageowner; //sets the stage to variable canvas
            this.radius = radius; //sets the radius

            buttons= new Array(vertical_rows);
            for (var t: int = 0; t<buttons.length; t++)
            {
                buttons[t] = new Button("Drop", t, (radius *2), 30, >button_clicked);
                buttons[t].x = (t * distBetweenCircles) + distFromCircleToWall - 15);
                buttons[t].y = 300;
                canvas.addChild(buttons[t]);
            }
        public function button_clicked( event:Event ):void
        {
            var button : Button = (Button)(event.currentTarget);
            **dropcheckerupdate(button.get_value());**
            trace("in button clicked");
            trace("button is: " + button.get_value());

        }
        private function find_first_available(col2:int) : int
        {
            var found: Boolean;
            var find_first_available_position: int;
            var currentCol = col2;
            trace(currentCol);

            for (var hor:int = 5; hor >-1 && found != true; hor= hor - 1)
                {
                    **if (grid [currentCol][hor].getOwner() == null)**
                    {
                        find_first_available_position = hor;
                        found = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        find_first_available_position = -1;
                    }
                }
            return find_first_available_position;
        }

        private function dropcheckerupdate(col : int):void
        {
            var currentCol = col;
            trace(currentCol);
            **var currentAvail = find_first_available(currentCol);**
            var currentPlayerName: String = "Player 1";

            if(currentAvail < 0)
            {
                return;
            }

            else
            {
                if (!player1Turn)
                {
                    currentPlayerName = "Player 2";
                }
                grid[currentCol][currentAvail] = currentPlayerName;
                var destPoint = new Point(distFromCircleToWall + distBetweenCircles * currentCol, distFromCircleToWall + (distBetweenCircles * currentAvail));
                var checker = new Checker(canvas, currentPlayerName, destPoint, radius + 1);
                trace("drop into column called with : " + currentCol);
                player1Turn = !player1Turn;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Also a tidbit from my button class

```
 private var title : String;
 private var value : int = 0;

      public function Button( my_title:String, my_id:int, my_width :int, my_height :int, call_back : Function) 
        {
         this.title  = my_title;
         this.value  = my_id;

          this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, create_mouse_down_display_list); 
          this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,   create_mouse_over_display_list); 
          this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER,  create_mouse_over_display_list); 
          this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT,   create_default_display_list);    
          this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,      call_back);

 .... further down .....
public function get_value() : int
        {
          return this.value;
        }
```

Comment: Please put only those part of code which where u are facing difficulties

Comment: The problem is on that first line mentioned in your stack trace: if (grid [currentCol][hor].getOwner() == null). It's likely that you haven't initialized a value in that two dimensional array.  Try logging each value of grid[currentCol] to find where the undefined value is.

Comment: You should use an IDE with a debugger, this will help you inspect the values of all variables/objects and it will make it easier to fix the problems.

Comment: Thanks Guys. This helped, indeed I hadn't initialized a value... but this was also a problem with my logic. To call .getOwner() by nature it would have to have had been assigned to an object, so it could never be equal to null.